# Formatting 24-hour time variable to capture observations in different ranges

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I currently have a data frame with a column for Start.Time (imported from a *.csv file), and the format is in 24 hour format (e.g., 20:00:00 equals 8pm). My goal is to capture observations with a start time in various intervals (e.g., between 9:00:00 and 10:00:00), which also meet other criteria. However, it seems that R sorts this 'character' variable in a way that does not align with how our day goes (e.g., 14:00:00 is considered a lower value than 9:00:00).

For example, below is a line of code that works as intended, where I am capturing observations on two different trail segments, which had a start time between 8:00:00 and 9:00:00.

```
RLLtoMist8.9<-sum((dataset1$Trail.Segment==52|dataset1$Trail.Segment==55) & 
                     (dataset1$Start.Time>="8:00" & dataset1$Start.Time < "9:00"),
                  na.rm=TRUE)
RLLtoMist8.9
```

But, this code  below does not work as intended, as R is 'valuing' 9:00:00 as greater than 10:00:00.

```
RLLtoMist9.10 <-
       sum((dataset1$Trail.Segment==52|dataset1$Trail.Segment==55) & 
           (dataset1$Start.Time>="9:00:00 AM" & dataset1$Start.Time < "10:00:00 AM"),
            na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly true that character types are sorted so that "14:00" is less than "9:00". However R has a datetime class which would sort times correctly once a character representation has been parsed.

```
a <- as.POSIXct("14:00", format="%H:%M")
b <- as.POSIXct("8:00", format="%H:%M")
# test
> a < b
[1] FALSE
```

You would be able to convert an entire column with:

```
dataset1$Start.Time <- as.POSIXct(dataset1$Start.Time,  format="%H:%M")
```

The dates of a and b were the system date at the time of conversion, so if you printed them you would see dates and times in the default format. There are packages, such as `chron`, that let you use just times, but POSIXt objects have dates and times necessarily. See `?DateTimeClasses`. The `lubridate` package also has an 'interval' class and there exist a `difftime` function in base-R.

There's also `seq.POSIXt` and `cut.POSIXt` functions, either of which could be used to create multiple time or date boundaries for  categorical transformations of datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data.table library:

```
# convert to data table 
dataset1<-data.table(dataset1)

# format to a date format rather that character
dataset1[, Start.Time := as.POSIXct(Start.Time, format="%H:%M:%S")]

#now do your filtering
dataset1[between(Start.Time, as.POSIXct("09:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("10:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S")) & (Trail.Segment==52 | Trail.Segment==55)]
```